# Bibliography and class apa6 help

Tags: biblatex, biber, apa6

I've tried Googling stuff, but all the guides are really unclear or I'm just stupid.

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6840 64-bit)

**EDIT** *the MWE, error log to match MWE.*

Suppose I have a `blahblahblah.tex` file as such:

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa6}

\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{blahblahblah.bib}


\title{Some Title}

\shorttitle{Some short title}

\author{Author 1, Author 2, Author 3}

\leftheader{last name 1, last name 2, last name 3}

\abstract{Abstract content}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}

Here is the content with a random citation \parencite{Hi, 1054}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and a `blahblahblah.bib` file as such

```
@article{blahblah,
title={blah title}, 
volume={11}, 
DOI={lsdkvnlskv}, 
number={1}, 
journal={bfljenflw}, 
author={Hi}, 
year={1054}, 
month={Jun}
}
```

Running the `.tex` file produces many errors. I am very confused.

Here is the error log from the edited MWE:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Hi' on page 1 undefined on input line 24.
LaTeX Warning: Citation '1054' on page 1 undefined on input line 24.
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 26.
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file: (biblatex)
blahblahblah (biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

Trying to make PK font rtxr at 600 DPI... The METFAONT mode is: ljfour
Running miktex-makemf.exe...
Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed.
The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going
again:

Running miktex-ttf2pk.exe...
Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed.
The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going
again:

!pdfTeX error: miktex-pdftex.exe (file rtxr): Font rtxr at 600 not
found  ==   Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following MWE (package `filecontents` is only used to have bib file and TeX code together in one compiling MWE)

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
@article{blahblah, 
    title={blah title}, 
    volume={11}, 
    DOI={lsdkvnlskv}, 
    number={1}, 
    journal={bfljenflw}, 
    author={welrknewlk, skfjekw}, 
    year={1054}, 
    month={Jun}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[jou]{apa6}

\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\title{Some Title}
\shorttitle{Some short title}
\author{Author 1, Author 2, Author 3}
\leftheader{last name 1, last name 2, last name 3}
\affiliation{xx} % <====================================================

\abstract{abstractedly distracted}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}

Here is the content with a random citation~\parencite{Goossens, adams}. 
Another citation~\parencite{blahblah}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I get no errors. Please see that I added the missing `\affiliation{xx}` to get rid of that warning and that I used `\parencite{Goossens, adams}` and `\parencite{blahblah}` to call the bib entries named `Goossens`, `adams` and `blahblah`.

then I get the resulting page:

[image]

Your problem with the font I do not have. I'm using an complete MiKTeX installation. Please update your system via MiKTeX conole and update all packages to your system.

You can proof if the font is installed on your system by checking the following directorys:

```
rtxr.afm    texmf\fonts\afm\public\txfonts
rtxr.pfb    texmf\fonts\type1\public\txfonts
rtxr.tfm    texmf\fonts\tfm\public\txfonts
```

For me it seems they are missing on your system ...

Comment: Thank you for a complete answer! I've resolved the issue now.